# How to pass Lambda values to a generic repository

Tags: .net, lambda, repository-pattern

I have a number of repositories in my app, and I want to try and make a generic repository to cut down on code duplication.

One requirement that comes up repeatedly is the need to list my entities in a drop down list.

In my current concrete repository I have this:

```
public IEnumerable GetSelectList()
{
    return _context.Cultures.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = x.CultureKey,
        Value = x.CultureID.ToString()
    }).ToList();
}
```

So what I would like to do is have a generic `GetSelectList` function that let me specify what values I wanted to use for the `Text` and `Value` fields in my select list item (in the code above those are `CultureKey` and `CultureID`).

I am not sure how I would make those values configurable in a generic repository. Is there a way to evaluate string values as lambda values? Or is there some other way of achieving what I want?

Comment: SelectListItem is "View" related and it will cause you pains in the future if you start mixing View logic with domain logic.  Alternatively, add a view helper or view model that converts specific fields to keys and values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puting aside the issue of whether a generic repository should know anythig about a `SelectListItem` (protip: it shouldn't) you can achieve this by passing in two lamda functions

```
public class GenericRepo<T>
{
    public IEnumerable GetSelectList(Func<T,string> text, Func<T,string> value)
    {
        return _context.Cultures.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text =  text(x),
            Value = value(x)
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Assuming you have an intance of `GenericRepo<Culture>` you would do this

```
var selectList = repo.GetSelectList(x => x.CultureKey, x => x.CultureID.ToString());
```

An arguably better way might be to decouple this, so your method returns a `IEnumerable<Tuple<string,string>>` and map that to a `SelectListItem` in your UI layer.

Comment: Completely take the point that this does not belong in the repository because of course it doesnt. accepting this answer as it answers the lambda question

Answer (score 0):

I think you should decouple your repositories from UI logic. It's not "correct" to mix UI specific logic as `SelectListItem` on you data access layer.

I'd implement whatever query you need on that method and build the list of `SelectListItem` on controller.

OTOH I don't think it's worth the effort to encapsulate the logic to create the list of `SelectListItem` once you move it to controller, you won't be gaining very much.

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` to convert to a list of `SelectListItems`:

```
public static class Extensions 
{

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, Func<T,string> text, Func<T,string> value)
    {
        return data.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = text(x),
            Value = value(x)
        });
    }
}
```

Now, all you need to do is call `.ToSelectList()` on your collections to convert each item to a select list item.  This is helpful because your not hiding the values you're using for the keys/values deep in your repository classes.

```
var results = _cultures.ToSelectList(o=>o.CultureKey, o=>o.CultureId.ToString());
```